# Simple equation not working?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, notation, arithmetic

So I found this equation
$$
  e^{20}=10^{20*.43429\dots} = 10^{8.6858\dots} = 10^9 * 10*(-.3141\dots)
$$
on this [webpage](https://web.archive.org/web/20180405022030/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/55611.html) and I'm really confused as to why it isn't matching up whenever I try it. The first two expressions are equal to each other but the third one doesn't equal either of them. Every time I calculate $10^9 * 10*(-.3141\dots)$ I get $-3414100000$ which is different from the other two expressions which equal $485165195.41$. I'm wondering if this is a mistake and if anyone can explain why this isn't working for me.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

On that webpage, the last expression has a typo. Rather than 
$$
  10\wedge 9 * 10*(-.3141\dots)
$$
it should be 
$$
  10\wedge 9 * 10\color{red}{\wedge}(-.3141\dots)
$$
This works out because $10^9 * 10^{-.3141}\approx 485176771.21$, which is about what you say the other ones are equal to.

Comment: Why are you using the wedge symbol?

Comment: @ericw31415 if you're writing mathematics without special formatting, you can use the wedge or carat to denote exponentation. So x^b is x to the power of b.

Comment: I'm wondering because $\wedge$ and $\mathrm{^}$ are quite different.